# SharePoint 2013 Upload file to folder in document library

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have the following code which places a file in a document library:

```
        public static void UploadFile(string siteURL, string libraryName, string file)
    {
        String fileToUpload = file;
        String sharePointSite = siteURL;
        String documentLibraryName = libraryName;

        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.RootWeb)
            {
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);

                SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

                // Prepare to upload
                Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
                String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
                FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

                // Upload document
                SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

                // Commit
                myLibrary.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to place the file inside of a folder in that library called "Nav"  I'm not sure how to make this happen.. I have tried but cannot get it into folder.

This was my latest effort:

```
SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName].SubFolders["Nav"];
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```
                SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];
                SPFolder subFolder = myLibrary.SubFolders["Nav"];
```

Seems messy but it works.. so I will live.